# Why free fall motion is parabolic?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, orbital-motion, projectile, free-fall

Consider no air resistance. If we throw a ball vertically upward from my point of view it goes vertically up and down and moving along straight line. But from point of view observer in outer space it is parabolic because of rotation of the earth. We know vertical acceleration/deceleration is due to earth gravity. But where component of velocity parallel to the Earth's surface come from to make parabolic path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The earth is rotating with a constant angular velocity ($2\pi$ radians, i.e., a whole revolution, per day). Each point on the earth's surface moves in such circles, and its linear speed is the tangent to these circles.

For example, if you're on the equator, whose length is approximately 40,000 km, and a full rotation takes approximately 86400 seconds (one day), then you are moving at linear speed of $40,000,000 m / 86,400 s$ = $462 m/s$. This is the component of velocity parallel to the Earth's surface which you mentioned.

Note that the speed depends on your lattitude. In one of the poles, it will be zero. Even from space, it will look like the ball jumps up and down, without additional movement. Well, that is - until you start considering also the fact that the earth is itself moving around the Sun!

Answer (score 2):

> But from point of view observer in outer space it is parabolic because of rotation of the earth.

This is not exactly correct. From the point of view of outer space it is a segment of an ellipse. However, if we approximate the gravitational field as a uniform field and if we talk about an observer in a car or train, then we can get the effect you describe.

> But where component of velocity parallel to the Earth's surface come from to make parabolic path?

It comes from the different initial conditions in the different reference frames. The laws of physics are written as differential equations. When you solve them you get a family of solutions. Going from the family of solutions to an individual solution requires specifying the initial conditions.

Here, the law of physics is $$\ddot {\vec x}=\vec g$$ which we can solve to get $$\vec x=\frac{1}{2}\vec g t^2 + \vec v_0 t + \vec x_0$$

So this same law of physics will give rise to a different trajectory for each initial condition $\vec v_0$, $\vec x_0$. In any case where $\vec v_0$ is parallel to $\vec g$ the motion is along a straight line. In any case where $\vec v_0$ has a component perpendicular to $\vec g$ then the motion is a parabola.

So, in the two cases in question, one has $\vec v_0$ parallel to $\vec g$ and the other does not. This accounts for the difference in the path.

Comment: Hello @Dale . But i have read on internet. When ball is in my hand ball rotate with earth , so ball has component of velocity parallel to the Earth due to earth rotation. This is where this component come from. Is it correct?

Comment: @123 yes ,,,,,,